# spam emails sent from my google account after laravel google smtp configuration

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, smtp, gmail

I recently setup my gmail account to send out automated emails for password reconfiguration and that sort of thing on my laravel project. And it works fine but this morning I got a message saying that my daily quota has been exceeded. Then I checked the sent folder of my gmail and I am seeing alot of emails I didn't send to some sketchy places. Has anyone had this sort of problem, and how do i secure this process so that it doesn't happen again?
[image]

Comment: Do check if you are able to access your `.env` through your webpage URL, but you have a security breach then... either the password was correctly guessed after some time, or it was exposed somehow

Comment: the .env file is not in the public folder. it is in the directory before the public folder. would i be able to add a .htaccess file to protect the .env file and if so how would i implement

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are posting your code (including sensitive information, i.e passwords) on an online forum or publicly available place. Other than that, I don't see reason for this to happen.